# ¿Cómo comparar dos arrays en php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas en la base de datos, **questions** y **user_answers** ambas tienen el campo *questionId*. Quiero comparar si un usuario ha respondido todas las preguntas de **questions**. Cada vez que un usuario responde una pregunta, se añade una nueva row en la tabla **user_answers**, con la *userId* de su cuenta y la *questionId* de la pregunta que acaba de responder. He pensado en comparar si todas las *questionId* de la tabla **questions**, han sido respondidas por el usuario *userId* en la tabla **user_answers**. Espero haber explicado bien el concepto.

He pensado en hacer una query a la tabla **questions** y que me devuelva un array con todas las *questionId*, y hacer otra query a la tabla **user_answers** con todas las *questionId* asociadas al usuario *userId*, es decir, el que está logueado en ese momento.

He intentado hacerlo, pero me quedo enganchado aquí:

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'connection.php';
include 'URLS.php';

$pregunta_sql = "SELECT questionId FROM questions;";
$pregunta_result = mysqli_query($connection, $pregunta_sql);
$pregunta_row = mysqli_fetch_array($pregunta_result);

$respuesta_sql = "SELECT questionId FROM user_answers WHERE userId = `$_SESSION['userId']`";
$respuesta_result = mysqli_query($connection, $respuesta_sql);
$respuesta_row = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta_result);

print_r($pregunta_row);
print_r($respuesta_row);
?>
```

No sé como obtener un array con todas las *questionId*, lo siento, soy bastante nuevo en php. Si a alguien se le ocurre un método mejor que comparar los dos arrays, lo agradecería.

Esto lo iba a preguntar en otro post, pero ya que es una pregunta corta... Una vez tenga los dos arrays, ¿Cómo puedo comparar cual es la *questionId* que no ha respondido el usuario?, Por ejemplo, si las *questionId* de **question** son `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` y el *userId* `1` ha respondido la `[2, 4, 5]`, como podría guardar en otro array `[1, 3]`? He visto que igual se puede con `array_diff()`.

Perdón por hacer esta pregunta tan larga, pero estoy un poco desesperado. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

**Método 1**

Si la intención es hacerlo con PHP bajo el concepto que planteaste, necesitas guardar en dos arrays diferentes tanto el contenido de las `questions` como de `user_asnswers`. Para eso te recomiendo hacerlo con el ciclo `while` (que explicar su funcionamiento está de más porque la estructura de control funciona igual que en cualquier otro lenguaje de programación).

Entonces, supongamos que tienes tu código así:

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'connection.php';
include 'URLS.php';

$pregunta_sql = "SELECT questionId FROM questions;";
$pregunta_result = mysqli_query($connection, $pregunta_sql);
$pregunta_row = mysqli_fetch_array($pregunta_result);

$respuesta_sql = "SELECT questionId FROM user_answers WHERE userId = `$_SESSION['userId']`";
$respuesta_result = mysqli_query($connection, $respuesta_sql);
$respuesta_row = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta_result);

print_r($pregunta_row);
print_r($respuesta_row);
?>
```

Lo que tenemos que hacer es modificar este código agregando los while mencionados y creando los dos arrays de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'connection.php';
include 'URLS.php';

$pregunta_sql = "SELECT questionId FROM questions;";
$pregunta_result = mysqli_query($connection, $pregunta_sql);

//inicializaremos nuestros arrays que ocuparemos y compararemos
$questions = array();
$user_answers = array();

//este ciclo terminará hasta que mysqli_fetch_array esté vacío o haya regresado un false
while ( $pregunta_row = mysqli_fetch_array($pregunta_result) ) {
   //y en cada vuelta guardaremos el contenido de cada row de la consulta
   $questions[] = $pregunta_row;
}


$respuesta_sql = "SELECT questionId FROM user_answers WHERE userId = `$_SESSION['userId']`";
$respuesta_result = mysqli_query($connection, $respuesta_sql);

//lo mismo hacemos para las respuestas del usuario
while ( $respuesta_row = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta_result) ) {
   //y en cada vuelta guardamos el contenido de la row de la consulta
   $user_answers[] = $respuesta_row;
}

?>
```

Una vez que tengamos los arrays `$users_answers` y `$questions` llenos empezamos con las comparaciones. Podemos hacerlo de varias formas, pero la que a mí más me gusta y recomiendo es recorrerlos y comparándolos. No se podría usar un `array_diff` debido a que no son dos arrays que tengan las mismas características (en cuanto a dimensión, tipos de datos, llaves, etc).

Entonces, recorremos agregando lo siguiente al final del código anterior:

```
<?php
//...
/*Recorremos el array $questions debido a que nos interesa saber de cada una de ellas cuál contestó el usuario y para eso nos apoyamos de la estructura de control foreach*/

//además creamos un array nuevo que llamaremos respuestas obtenidas donde guardaremos las respuestas que el usuario dio
$respuestas_usuarios = array();
foreach ( $questions as $mQuestion ) {
  //recorremos el array de $users_answers en cada item del array $question para saber si el id se encuentra dentro del array $users_answers y que coincida con el elemento actual iterado llamado $mQuestion
  foreach ( $user_answers as $mUserAnswer ) {
    if ( $mQuestion["id_question"] == $mUserAnswer["id_question"]) {
       //si el id_question de la respuesta actual iterada del usuario loggeado y obtenido previamente coincide con una de las preguntas de la tabla preguntas entonces guardamos esa pregunta en el array $respuestas_usuarios
       $respuestas_usuarios[] = $mQuestion;
    }
  }
}

//...
?>
```

Y ahora sí, una vez agregado el código anterior, ya sabremos qué preguntas ha respondido el usuario y que tenemos disponible en el array `$respuestas_usuarios`.

Ahora lo que nos toca hacer con esto es dependiendo de qué queramos mostrar.

Si por ejemplo queremos mostrar cuáles son las respuestas que el usuario ha contestado, imprimiremos (además de guardar en el array $respuestas_usuarios) con un indicador esa pregunta contestada o no.

```
<?php
    //...
    /*Recorremos el array $questions debido a que nos interesa saber de cada una de ellas cuál contestó el usuario y para eso nos apoyamos de la estructura de control foreach*/

    //además creamos un array nuevo que llamaremos respuestas obtenidas donde guardaremos las respuestas que el usuario dio
    $respuestas_usuarios = array();
    foreach ( $questions as $mQuestion ) {

       echo "Pregunta #{$mQuestion['id_question']} ";

      //recorremos el array de $users_answers en cada item del array $question para saber si el id se encuentra dentro del array $users_answers y que coincida con el elemento actual iterado llamado $mQuestion
      foreach ( $user_answers as $mUserAnswer ) {
        if ( $mQuestion["id_question"] == $mUserAnswer["id_question"]) {
           //si el id_question de la respuesta actual iterada del usuario loggeado y obtenido previamente coincide con una de las preguntas de la tabla preguntas entonces guardamos esa pregunta en el array $respuestas_usuarios
           $respuestas_usuarios[] = $mQuestion;
           //Además de guardar la pregunta contestada en el array imprimos el indicador de "Contestada"
           echo "Contestada";
        }
        else {
           //Si la pregunta aún no fue respondida entre las respuestas obtenidas del usuario vamos a imprimir un "No contestada"
           echo "No contestada";
        }
      }

     echo "<br>";
    }
    //...
?>
```

Al final el resulado del código anterior, quedaría como resultado, por ejemplo, así:

```
Pregunta #1 Contestada
Pregunta #2 Contestada
Pregunta #3 No Contestada
```

**Método 2**

**¿Cómo sé cuáles preguntas ha respondido un usuario?**

Con SQL podemos saberlo. Supongamos que tenemos esta siguiente estructura que por lo que comentas es así:

1. Tabla questions
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Tabla user_answers
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quisiéramos saber de un golpe las preguntas que el usuario con id 1 ha respondido, haríamos una consulta como la siguiente:

```
SELECT questions.*, user_answers.id_user  FROM user_answers INNER JOIN questions ON (user_answers.id_question = questions.id_question) WHERE user_answers.id_user = 1
```

Con la anterior consulta lo que estamos haciendo es hacer una relación con el campo `id_question`, es decir, una intersección que donde en ambas tablas coincidan este campo. El resto de las filas que no coincidan en essta condición o no intersecten, serán ignoradas.

El resultado de la anterior consulta quedaría como:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso la intersección solo se hace efectiva con los id_queston 1 y 2, ya que el 3 no existe en la tabla de user_answers, entonces la consulta no debe de mostrar esta última fila.

**¿Cómo sé cuáles preguntas ha respondido un usuario y además traer el listado de todas las preguntas?**

Esto podemos hacerlo muy similar a la consulta previa, agregando un campo indicador que nos sirva para saber si contestó o no esa pregunta.

La consulta quedaría así:

```
SELECT questions.*, user_answers.id_user, (IFNULL(user_answers.id_user, 0)) pregunta_respondida  FROM user_answers LEFT JOIN questions ON (user_answers.id_question = questions.id_question) WHERE user_answers.id_user = 1
```

La anterior consulta guarda en un campo llamado `pregunta_respondida` el id del usuario que encontró en la tabla de `user_answers`. En caso de que fuera NULO (debido a que el LEFT JOIN resultó un nulo o una no intersección) se le va a poner un número 0. Esto puede después leerse con PHP e imprimir un indicador como "Contestado" o "No contestado" con una condicionante if, ejemplo:

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'connection.php';
include 'URLS.php';

$consulta_final = "SELECT questions.*, user_answers.id_user, (IFNULL(user_answers.id_user, 0)) pregunta_respondida  FROM user_answers LEFT JOIN questions ON (user_answers.id_question = questions.id_question) WHERE user_answers.id_user = " . $_SESSION["id_usuario"];
$consulta_final_result = mysqli_query($connection, $consulta_final);

while ( $consulta_row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_final_result) ) {
   echo "Pregunta #{$consulta_final_result['id_question']} ";
   if ( $consulta_row["pregunta_respondida"] > 0 ) {
     echo "Pregunta respondida";
   }
   else {
     echo "No respondida";
   }
   echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

El resultado tendría que ser el mismo anterior explicado como:

```
Pregunta #1 Contestada
Pregunta #2 Contestada
Pregunta #3 No Contestada
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por dar una respuesta tan elaborada, me pasé muchas horas intentado averiguarlo, de hecho, pubiqué la pregunta en stackoverflow en inglés (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61398925/how-to-compare-two-responses-in-php/), me recomendaron usar JOIN. Pero al final he acabado usando `SELECT questionId FROM questions EXCEPT SELECT questionId FROM user_answers WHERE userId = $_SESSION['userId'];` (con las comillas bien puestas), me devuelve las `questionId` que no ha respondido el usuario `userId`. No tengo mas espacio para responder, gracias por tu ayuda :)